# sass source map issues on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, sass, gruntjs

I recently updated to OSX Yosemite and now, when I run Grunt and make changes to the sass file in my project, I receive the following error:

```
Warning: Error: Error generating source map: couldn't determine public URL for the source stylesheet.
         No filename is available so there's nothing for the source map to link to.
        on line  of standard input
  Use --trace for backtrace. Use --force to continue.
```

I have made no other changes to my Grunt setup or sass:dist, dependencies are unchanged and so forth. Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can have more than one reason, maybe this will help you.

Before starting remove the compiled css!

- Update grunt-contrib-sass to the latest version
- Sourcemap Requires Sass 3.4.0, which can be installed with gem install sass
- Run grunt sass task and review compiled css.

When everything is updated, the sourcemap should be automatically created and available. Be sure to empty browser cache before testing in the browser.